# SendMessage COPYDATASTRUCT wrong string when recive in delphi

Tags: c++, winapi, delphi-xe

I send the following c++ application request:

```
string data_to_send = "Hello World";
PCSTR lpszString = data_to_send.c_str();
COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = 0; // can be anything
cds.cbData = sizeof(TCHAR) * (data_to_send.size());
cds.lpData = &lpszString;
cout << lpszString << endl;
SendMessage(Output, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)Output, (LPARAM)(PVOID)&cds);
```

I get the structure using the following code in Delphi

```
var
  p : PCopyDataStruct;
  s : UTF8String;
begin
  p := PCopyDataStruct(Message.lParam);
  if (p <> nil) then
  begin
    SetString(s, PAnsiChar(p^.lpData), p^.cbData);
    ShowMessage(s);
  end else
    inherited;
end;
```

The string looks wrong.
In the debugger, it is equal to the following

```
'l'#$FE#$F6#2'Hello World'#0#$10#3#$88'u'#$B#0
```

We see 22 bytes with an extra 4 bytes before the message.
If we use CHAR instead of TCHAR, then we see 11 bytes, but again with an offset of 4 bytes

```
#$18#$F9#$1B#3'Hello W'
```

Please, help!!!

## **UPDATE:**

Thanks to [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) for his help, his code does everything as it was originally intended and  [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) for the correct remark! They saved me. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74309935/16466186) is the working code.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing Unicode and ansi strings

Comment: Send lpszString rather than &lpszString. Also stop using TCHAR. You are sending array of char.

Comment: @Daniel A. White , I agree with you. Sending messages in the opposite direction works correctly. `ToSend := 'Hello World';
s := UTF8String(ToSend);
copyDataStruct.dwData := MyDataID; //use it to identify the message contents
copyDataStruct.cbData := Length(s) * SizeOf(AnsiChar);
copyDataStruct.lpData := PAnsiChar(s);
res := SendMessage(receiverHandle, WM_COPYDATA, WPARAM(Handle), LPARAM(@copyDataStruct));`

Comment: @AgniusIgres After your update, you are now sending all 1024 `char`s, even though you populate only 11 `char`s. If you are going to use a fixed `char[]` array instead of a `std::string`, then consider using `strlen()` for `cds.cbData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the C++ side:

- `cds.dwData` should not be 0. Use a more unique value, such as the result of calling `RegisterWindowMessage()`.  Many apps, and even the VCL internally, use `WM_COPYDATA` for different purposes, so you don't want to get confused with someone else's message by mistake.
- `sizeof(TCHAR)` should be `sizeof(char)` instead (or omitted entirely, since `sizeof(char)` is always 1).
- `cds.lpData = &lpszString;` needs to be `cds.lpData = lpszString;` instead.  You are sending the address of the `lpszString` variable itself, not the address of the character data it points at.  That is why you are seeing garbage on the other end - you are seeing random bytes from the call stack where `lpszString` resides, which in your case includes the `std::string` object (whose internal members happen to include a Short-String-Optimization buffer, which is why you are also seeing your characters, too).

On the Delphi side:

- you should validate `p^.dwData` is your unique number before processing the message any further. If the number does not match what you are expecting, pass the message to the `inherited` handler and move on.
- `UTF8String` should be `AnsiString`, unless the sender's `std::string` is actually UTF-8 encoded.

Try this:

```cpp
const UINT uMyDataID = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("MyDataID"));
...
if (uMyDataID != 0)
{
    string data_to_send = u8"Hello World";
    COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
    cds.dwData = uMyDataID;
    cds.cbData = sizeof(char) * data_to_send.size();
    cds.lpData = const_cast<char*>(data_to_send.c_str());
    // or: cds.lpData = data_to_send.data(); in C++17 and later
    SendMessage(Output, WM_COPYDATA, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(Output), reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&cds));
}
```

```pascal
var
  uMyDataID: UINT = 0;
...
procedure TMyForm.WMCopyData(var Message: TMessage);
var
  p : PCopyDataStruct;
  s : UTF8String;
begin
  p := PCopyDataStruct(Message.lParam);
  if (uMyDataID <> 0) and (p <> nil) and (p^.dwData = uMyDataID) then
  begin
    SetString(s, PAnsiChar(p^.lpData), p^.cbData);
    ShowMessage(s);
  end else
    inherited;
end;
...
initialization
  uMyDataID := RegisterWindowMessage('MyDataID');
```

Comment: `cds.lpData = data_to_send.c_str();`   Compilation error : a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "PVOID ". The problem has already been solved and the post has been updated, but I will add your edits about `p^.dwData`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AgniusIgres I had already corrected the `c_str` issue before you posted that comment